# vertx run with metrics enabled in cluster

Tags: java, vert.x

- OS: Linux
- Vert.x Version: 3.3.3
- Machines: Two different with
  different IP within same subnet

I want to enable metrics monitoring for an simple ping-pong application, where I can watch how many packets were sent between the two nodes.

The measured metrics should be pushed over the eventbus and consumed by a website, providing a dashboard. Copied from the [vertx examples on Github](https://github.com/vert-x3/vertx-examples/blob/master/metrics-examples/src/main/java/io/vertx/example/metrics/dashboard/Dashboard.java)

Starting apps with following commands

**Sender**:

```
vertx run de.avm.boundary.Sender -cluster -cp target/vertx-ping-pong-3.3.3-fat.jar -Dvertx.metrics.options.enabled=true
```

**Receiver**

```
vertx run de.avm.boundary.Receiver -cluster -cp target/vertx-ping-pong-3.3.3-fat.jar
```

doesn't provide any metrics.

---

Source Code

**Sender.java**

```
package de.avm.boundary;

import io.vertx.core.AbstractVerticle;
import io.vertx.core.Handler;
import io.vertx.core.Vertx;
import io.vertx.core.http.HttpServer;
import io.vertx.core.json.JsonObject;
import io.vertx.core.logging.Logger;
import io.vertx.core.logging.LoggerFactory;
import io.vertx.ext.dropwizard.MetricsService;
import io.vertx.ext.web.Router;
import io.vertx.ext.web.handler.StaticHandler;
import io.vertx.ext.web.handler.sockjs.BridgeOptions;
import io.vertx.ext.web.handler.sockjs.PermittedOptions;
import io.vertx.ext.web.handler.sockjs.SockJSHandler;

public class Sender extends AbstractVerticle {

Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(getClass().getSimpleName());

@Override
public void start() {
    Vertx.currentContext().config();
    System.out.println("START SENDER VERTICLE DEPLOYMENT ID: " + deploymentID());

    BridgeOptions bridgeOptions = new BridgeOptions().
            addOutboundPermitted(
                    new PermittedOptions().
                            setAddress("metrics-sender")
            ).addOutboundPermitted(new PermittedOptions().
                    setAddressRegex("metrics-receiver")
    );

    Router router = Router.router(vertx);
    router.route("/eventbus/*").handler(SockJSHandler.create(vertx).bridge(bridgeOptions));
    router.route().handler(StaticHandler.create());

    HttpServer httpServer = vertx.createHttpServer();
    httpServer.requestHandler(router::accept).listen(8080);
    //why is the service object null ??
    MetricsService service = MetricsService.create(vertx.eventBus());
    System.out.println("Metrics-Service: " + service);
    vertx.setPeriodic(100, new Handler<Long>() {
        @Override
        public void handle(Long timerID) {
            vertx.eventBus().publish("ping-address", "more news! at: " + System.currentTimeMillis());
        }
    });

    vertx.setPeriodic(1000, new Handler<Long>() {
        @Override
        public void handle(Long timerID) {
            JsonObject metrics = service.getMetricsSnapshot(vertx);
            vertx.eventBus().publish("metrics-sender", metrics);
            System.out.println("Metrics: " + metrics);
        }
    });
}
}
```

**Receiver.java**

```
package de.avm.boundary;

import io.vertx.core.AbstractVerticle;
import io.vertx.core.AsyncResult;
import io.vertx.core.Handler;
import io.vertx.core.eventbus.Message;
import io.vertx.core.json.JsonObject;
import io.vertx.ext.dropwizard.MetricsService;

public class Receiver extends AbstractVerticle {

    MetricsService service = MetricsService.create(vertx);

    @Override
    public void start() {
        System.out.println("START RECEIVER VERTICLE DEPLOYMENT ID: " + deploymentID());

        vertx.eventBus().consumer("ping-address", new Handler<Message<String>>() {
            @Override
            public void handle(Message<String> message) {
                // Reply to it
                System.out.println("Received message: " + message.body());
                message.reply("pong!");
            }

        }).completionHandler(new Handler<AsyncResult<Void>>() {
            @Override
            public void handle(AsyncResult<Void> event) {
                if (event.succeeded()) {
                    System.out.println("Eventbus registration complete!");
                }
            }
        });

        // Send a metrics events every second
        vertx.setPeriodic(1000, t -> {
            JsonObject metrics = service.getMetricsSnapshot(vertx.eventBus());
            vertx.eventBus().publish("metrics-receiver", metrics);
        });
    }
}
```

pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0
                      http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>de.avm</groupId>
    <artifactId>vertx-ping-pong</artifactId>
    <version>3.3.3</version>


    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.vertx</groupId>
            <artifactId>vertx-core</artifactId>
            <version>${project.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.vertx</groupId>
            <artifactId>vertx-dropwizard-metrics</artifactId>
            <version>${project.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.vertx</groupId>
            <artifactId>vertx-hazelcast</artifactId>
            <version>${project.version}</version>
            <!--<scope>provided</scope>-->
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.vertx</groupId>
            <artifactId>vertx-web</artifactId>
            <version>${project.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.vertx</groupId>
            <artifactId>vertx-lang-js</artifactId>
            <version>${project.version}</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>


    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.3</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>shade</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <transformers>
                                <transformer
                                        implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ManifestResourceTransformer">
                                    <manifestEntries>
                                        <Main-Class>io.vertx.core.Launcher</Main-Class>
                                        <Main-Verticle>de.avm.boundary.Sender</Main-Verticle>
                                    </manifestEntries>
                                </transformer>
                            </transformers>
                            <artifactSet/>
                            <outputFile>${project.build.directory}/${project.artifactId}-${project.version}-fat.jar</outputFile>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.3</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

How can I enable Metrics?

Comment: You publish your metrics, but you never consume them. Or you didn't post the code where you do.

Comment: Mentioned by a link to official Vertx examples in the first part within this question. Using the dashboard website. But the main problem is, that metrics is not enabled, when starting the Application.
It seems that the given option `-Dvertx.metrics.options.enabled=true` is not considered.

Answer (score 1):

Solved the problem by changing starting appliaction, especially the Sender an Receiver Verticles, in another war.

The best solution for me was starting the application with

**Sender:**

```
java -jar target/vertx-ping-pong-3.3.3-Sender-fat.jar -cluster -Dvertx.metrics.options.enabled=true
```

**Receiver**

```
java -jar target/vertx-ping-pong-3.3.3-Receiver-fat.jar -cluster -Dvertx.metrics.options.enabled=true
```

The pitfall is, that you must tell maven, especially the shade plugin, which them main class is. I have achieved this by defining a placeholder within the properties part in the pom.xml and passing the name of the main Vericle during maven build execution.

```
mvn package -DmainClass=Sender
```

This also results to place a fat-jar withing the target folder where the name of the passed parameter is included in the file name.

Here the modified `pom.xml`

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0
                      http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>de.avm</groupId>
    <artifactId>vertx-ping-pong</artifactId>
    <version>3.3.3</version>
    <properties>
        <runWithClass>${mainClass}</runWithClass>
    </properties>


    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.vertx</groupId>
            <artifactId>vertx-core</artifactId>
            <version>${project.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.vertx</groupId>
            <artifactId>vertx-dropwizard-metrics</artifactId>
            <version>${project.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.vertx</groupId>
            <artifactId>vertx-hazelcast</artifactId>
            <version>${project.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.vertx</groupId>
            <artifactId>vertx-web</artifactId>
            <version>${project.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.vertx</groupId>
            <artifactId>vertx-lang-js</artifactId>
            <version>${project.version}</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>


    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.3</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>shade</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <transformers>
                                <transformer
                                        implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ManifestResourceTransformer">
                                    <manifestEntries>
                                        <Main-Class>io.vertx.core.Launcher</Main-Class>
                                        <Main-Verticle>de.avm.boundary.${runWithClass}</Main-Verticle>
                                    </manifestEntries>
                                </transformer>
                            </transformers>
                            <artifactSet/>
                            <outputFile>${project.build.directory}/${project.artifactId}-${project.version}-${runWithClass}-fat.jar</outputFile>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.3</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```